# How is that the "stockpiling power" of One for All hurts Deku, but the "stockpiling kinetic energy" of Fa Jin doesnt?

Tags: my-hero-academia

Deku can now reach "pseudo 100%" of his power by using One for All 45% plus the quirk Fa Jin. How is that the real 100% of power hurts his body, but the pseudo 100% of power of One for All 45%+ Fa Jin doesnt?

Comment: Only time will tell since this happend in the most recent manga chapter and we will probably get an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer based on real-world science. Kinetic energy cannot destroy things neither can it destroy itself